# How to setup XDebug properly in PhpStorm for Laravel web app that run in Vagrant? (Mac OS X)

Tags: php, apache, laravel, vagrant, phpstorm

I have my Laravel web app run inside Vagrant, using `precise64` box.

In vagrant box: 
in directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` , I have `000-default.conf` and `laratest.conf` file. I'm only interested in `laratest.conf` right now.

Inside laratest.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName laratest.dev
   ServerAlias www.laratest.dev
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laratest/public

  <Directory /var/www/laratest/public>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>     
</VirtualHost>
```

In my `php.ini` file from `/etc/php5/apache2/` directory:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="./usr/lib/php5/some-number/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey="vagrant"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

So, I access my laravel web with `laratest.dev` url

In `PHPStorm -> Preferences -> Project Settings -> PHP -> Servers` , the image below is my setup:
[image]

I already enable listener in PHP Debug Connection (Phone icon) and put a breakpoint. The breakpoint manage to hit when I run the web, but it give this error:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with my set up? Especially mapping. I have tried so many things and googling, still can't debug properly yet

Comment: Visually your mappings look just fine. Question is -- 1) have you EVER renamed ANY folder in the `/Users/admin/code/websites/Laratest/` path? 2) Any symbolic links (both local and especially remote) ?? 3) xdebug version

Comment: @LazyOne
1) I never rename any folder, just chmod  app/storage
2) No symbolic links. But my xdebug.ini reside in '/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini', and from phpinfo(), the Additional .ini files parsed show the location in '/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini'.Do I need to write xdebug stuff in xdebug.ini or php.ini?
3) xdebug version 2.2.3

Comment: 1) I suggest deleting ALL entries in "Preferences | PHP | Servers` -- on next debug connection IDE will help you to set it up correctly. See if it will work (not just for one session, but for many files/session) 2) You are receiving incoming debug connection so whatever settings are seems to work (double check xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output). cannot advise you the correct file to edit as I'm not using Mac/Linux myself (I just know that on some Linux distribs Apache uses different .ini file as compared to CLI one .. so always check phpinfo() in the same environment)

Comment: Based on symptoms and the fact that IDE runs on Mac (based on file paths) .. I still think about #1. Could you please go into terminal and check EVERY folder in this path there (`/Users/admin/code/websites/Laratest/`) -- I've seen similar behaviour before (5 or 6 times) when folder was renamed from e.g. `admin` to `Admin` (i.e. same name but different letter casing) -- in Finder it looks normal but in terminal it still has OLD casing .. and IDE fails here. Once again -- this idea is about Mac side only - does not apply to Linux

Comment: @LazyOne Everything run on linux actually (virtual box), all the path I show is located in vagrant precise64 box, only my PhpStorm reside in Mac

Comment: Where are the project files are located on Mac ?? Or you accessing source files directly over the network (which does not look like)?

Comment: @LazyOne as you can see in the picture above (PHPStorm -> Preferences -> Project Settings -> PHP -> Servers) , the whole file is in directory '/Users/admin/code/websites/Laratest' in Mac OSX . While in Virtualbox it points to '/var/www/Laratest/public'

Comment: Yes .. I clearly see that. That's why in my very first comment I have stated that mappings look OK. Problem is ... IDE cannot find the `index.php` file .. despite the fact that paths entered correctly. So ... 1) have you tried my suggestion with deleting all server entries and letting IDE setting them up fr you (have not received answer for that)? 2) What debug logs say about it (xdebug as well as from PhpStorm side -- http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202)? -- post the link to them

Comment: @LazyOne I solve the issue already. It turns out my mapping is the culprit. Thanks for your help

Comment: TBH -- it should have worked even without such additional mapping (always works for me) as it should propagate accordingly to all children elements. Cannot say why it did not worked for you in first place and what else (aside from already mentioned) may have caused this. In any case -- it's working now, one way or another.

Comment: @LazyOne so it works both way for you? Interesting...

Comment: Why it should not? Children elements (folders/files) automatically inherit mappings from parent. In most cases (when no symbolic links used) setting up single root mapping is enough. Accordingly to what I see from your screenshots (your working mapping) you do not have symbolic links there. If you wish (have time and desire) create brand new simple test project with few subfolders and try on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is the correct mapping I needed to make it to works

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for group routes under prefix, take care when you want todo that.